# Publishing NET Maui fails with different issues

Tags: c#, maui

I was working on one tool and everything was running fine. Was able to publish. However after recent update to **Visual Studio 17.7.1** I am getting all kind of issues that do not make any sense. For example recently, it started to output the following:

> 1>Assets file
> 'C:\Users\username\source\repos\vpr\vpr\obj\project.assets.json'
> doesn't have a target for 'net7.0'. Ensure that restore has run and
> that you have included 'net7.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your
> project.

but this project has following `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Sometimes it is also complaining the same about other projects, but they have `net7.0` set. Sometimes there are other errors, but non of them is making really sense.

1. I have tried setting this to Self Contained to `True` and `False`:

   [image]
2. I have also tried to delete all `bin` and `obj` from all of the projects and use `Clean` solution and each project and then `Rebuild` with no success.
3. I have also tried to run `dotnet restore -r win-x86` and `dotnet restore -r win-x64`.
4. I have also tried to reinstall Visual Studio. So currently I can not roll back to previous version of Visual Studio.

My application is running fine in `Debug` and `Release`, but publishing is messed up. I don't remember changing anything crucial before and after Visual Studio update. Does anybody else facing the same issues with recent Visual Studio update and are there any other options to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I did is to ignore Visual Studio and followed guidelines provided by microsoft

This is a tutorial I followed to [publish .NET MAUI Application for Android](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli) Platform from CLI

I'm sure you will exactly solve your problems from these guidelines because this works for me for several .NET MAUI Projects.

Here is powershell script for automated versioning and publishing for windows

```
$FilePath = "Platforms/Windows/Package.appxmanifest"


#Load XML Content
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $FilePath)



# Get identity Element
$IdentityElement = $xml.Package.Identity

echo "Your Current Version"
$IdentityElement.Version
echo "________________________"

# Get the current version Number
$version = $IdentityElement.Version.Split(".") | ForEach-Object { [int]$_ }

# Increment values

$response = Read-Host "Do you Update Major Version ? (Y / N) "

if($response -eq "y" -or $response -eq "Y"){
    $version[0]++
}

$response = Read-Host "Do you Update Minor Version ? (Y / N) "

if($response -eq "y" -or $response -eq "Y"){
    $version[1]++
}
$response = Read-Host "Do you Update Build Number ? (Y / N) "

if($response -eq "y" -or $response -eq "Y"){
    $version[2]++
}
$response = Read-Host "Do you Update Revision Number ? (Y / N) "

if($response -eq "y" -or $response -eq "Y"){
    $version[3]++
}

# Update version with new one
$IdentityElement.Version = "$($version[0]).$($version[1]).$($version[2]).$($version[3])"

$CLoc = Get-Location


$combined = Join-Path $CLoc $FilePath


# Save the updated xml files
$xml.Save($combined)

$resp = Read-Host "Do you want to build now? (Y/N)"

if($resp -eq "Y" -or $resp -eq "y"){
    dotnet publish -f net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -c Release
}

Pause
```

This is powershell script for android

```
$FilePath = "Platforms/Android/AndroidManifest.xml"

$xml = [xml](Get-Content $FilePath)

$currentVersion = $xml.manifest.'versionCode'

$re = Read-Host "Do you wish to increment version number ? (Y / N)";

if($re -eq "Y" -or $re -eq "y"){
    $newVersion = [int]$currentVersion + 1
    $versionName = Read-Host "Give Version Name : "
    $xml.manifest.'versionCode' = $newVersion.ToString()
    $xml.manifest.versionName = $versionName.ToString()
}

$CLoc = Get-Location


$combined = Join-Path $CLoc $FilePath


# Save the updated xml files
$xml.Save($combined)

$resp = Read-Host "Do you want to build now? (Y/N)"

if($resp -eq "Y" -or $resp -eq "y"){
    dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=[your_pwd] /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=[your_pwd]
}

Pause
```

Comment: What do you mean by pipeline? Is there some automated way to publish it somehow more faster? I am currently publishing quite frequently for testing purposes, so would be good to save some minutes here and there

Comment: check github workflow CI/CD pipelines or Azure devops pipelines both are works for me for .NET MAUI